# Custom filter template with vritual scroll in PrimeNg not visible?

Tags: angular2-template, primeng, primeng-datatable

```
I am creating my own template filter in primeNg Datatable. It working 
without any issue.
But when I use the same template on virtual scroll it is being cut buy table 
body. Not visible. I tried multiple hit and trial but no luck.
```

I added ``` <template pTemplate = "body">``<template pTemplate = "header"> ```

```
but none of them working i tried all possble CSS as well.
Please see the plunk without virtual and with virtual scroll:
```

[Plunk without virtual scroll](http://plnkr.co/edit/4i2exay9ZpPGt2QQZ7sM?p=preview) **Div visible**

[Plunk with virtual scroll](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxPlDQIksdlyBURgbHiu?p=preview) **Div not visible**

Comment: Forgot to add : to see the issue please click on filter icon in first coloumn.

Answer (score 0):

```
Some how i manage to solve this issue. Using position fixed and z-index: 1
I have added z-index because in real app it was behind the table rows.
plunker is updated now with sol.
```

```js
<div *ngIf='showDiv' style=" width: 150px; height: 200px;
                        position:fixed;
                        z-index: 1;
                        border:1px solid grey;
                        overflow: visible;
                        background-color: ghostwhite;">
```

[updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YxPlDQIksdlyBURgbHiu?p=preview) working

Comment: Hope this will help someone to create there own custom filter box. If someone have better alternate solution please post your answer.